# Why does IE11 resize elements to a wrong size with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have a DIV element in a HTML page. When the mouse enters the element, the width increases by 200 pixels with Javascript. When the mouse leaves the element, the width is reduced by -200 pixels back to the previous value. The page also has an "increase" and a "decrease" button which have the same effect. There's also a "reset" button which will resize the element back to the original size it had at the moment of loading the page.

In Chrome and Firefox everything is working fine. I tested the page in IE11 and I had 2 problems:

1. The element's width increases by 199.99 and decreases by 200.01 pixels.
2. Clicking on the reset button will resize the element to less than the initial width.

Can anyone give me a clue why does this happen? The first problem might be due to rounding up, but the second doesn't seem to make any sense to me.

Here's the HTML, CSS and JS.

```js
$(function() {

  var initialWidth = getWidth(); // storing in the initialWidth variable the width of the #test element at the moment of loading the page

  function getWidth() { // getter for the width (in pixels) of the #test element
    return $("#test").width();
  }

  function informWidth() { // updating the #wids element with the #test element's width (in pixels)
    $("#wids").text(getWidth());
  }

  informWidth(); // when the page is loaded, the width of the #test element is informed

  $("#initWidth").text(initialWidth);
  /* 
      when the page is loaded, the initial width of the #test element is informed. 
      As this information is not subject to change, the #initWidth element will never 
      be refreshed by this script
      */

  function animateWider(elem, increment, durat) {
    /*
        this function will increase an element's width by a certain amount of pixels or percentage with an animation effect, 
            then the new width of the #test element will be informed by refreshing the #wids element.
        elem = the element to be enlarged
        increment = amount of pixels or percentage by which the element is enlarged
        durat = animation's duration in milliseconds
        */
    increment = '+=' + increment; // the value in pixels
    elem.animate({
      width: increment
    }, durat, function() {
      informWidth();
    });
  }

  function animateNarrower(elem, decrement, durat) {
    /*
        this function will reduce an element's width by a certain amount of pixels or percentage with an animation effect, 
            then the new width of the #test element will be informed by refreshing the #wids element.
        elem = the element to be enlarged
        decrement = amount of pixels or percentage by which the element is narrowed
        durat = animation's duration in milliseconds
        */
    decrement = '-=' + decrement;
    elem.animate({
      width: decrement
    }, durat, function() {
      informWidth();
    });
  }

  function animateWidth(elem, newWidth, durat) {
    /*
        this function will change an element's width to a certain amount of pixels with an animation effect, 
            then the new width of the #test element will be informed by refreshing the #wids element.
        elem = the element to be enlarged
        decrement = the new element's width in pixels
        durat = animation's duration in milliseconds
        */
    elem.animate({
      width: newWidth
    }, durat, function() {
      informWidth();
    });
  }

  $("#test").mouseenter(function() { // when the mouse enters the #test element its width will be increased
    animateWider($("#test"), 200, 1000); // In IE11 the value must be 200.01 for the script to properly work!!!
  });

  $("div").mouseleave(function() { // when the mouse enters the #test element its width will be decreased
    animateNarrower($("#test"), 200, 1000); // In IE11 the value must be 199.99 for the script to properly work!!!
  });

  $("#incr").click(function() { // clicking the #incr button will mimic the mouse entering the #test element
    $("#test").trigger("mouseenter");
  });

  $("#decr").click(function() { // clicking the #decr button will mimic the mouse leaving the #test element
    $("#test").trigger("mouseleave");
  });

  $("#test").click(function() { // clicking on the #test element will refresh the information about its width
    informWidth();
  });

  $("p").click(function() { // clicking on the <p> will refresh the information about the #test element's width
    informWidth();
  });

  $("#reset").click(function() {
    /*
        In IE11 The initial width of the #test DIV element is 
        230.589996337891 px, but if you click on the RESET button 
        the element's width will change to 230.579986572266 px 
        without any apparent reason!!!
        */
    alert("the value of the initialWidth variable is " + initialWidth); // this alert shows how the new
    // #test's width won't match the
    // value of initialWidth
    animateWidth($("#test"), initialWidth, 1000);
  });

});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}
button {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 225px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">We are writing a long text here now</div>
<p>Box width is (click here to update): <span id=wids></span>, initial width is <span id=initWidth></span>
</p>
<button id="decr">DECREASE 200px</button>
<br />
<button id="incr">INCREASE 200px</button>
<br />
<button id="reset">RESET</button>
```

Comment: There is such a thing as "too many comments". Try to cut down on comments in favor of code that can be readily understood. Not writing comments improves your programming ability in two ways : 1) You learn to read code, not text. 2) You notice the sections of code that could use simplification.

Comment: The # of comments & type of comments that would be considered too many is subjective, but it is definitely a thing! For example: echo $pageTitle; //echo page title to page

Comment: And there's a danger of comments that repeat what the code says. They become out of sync with the code. Now, wenn you read the comment, and see the code, and they are different, which should you believe? Is the comment mistaken, or is the code wrong? Apart from that they bind time, they impose a certain way of thinking on the reader, and they rapidly become outdated as you progress in your skills. Don't write comments that say what the code does. The code says what it does. Write comments that say stuff the code can't say, like *"this exists to work around IE bug XYZ, see http://link"*.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm still looking for the right balance when it comes to comments. Btw that link doesn't work, could you please post it again? Also, it looks like everything was fixed by just adding that line into the page and importing ajax. Could you please explain how that was possible? @Tomalak